# How to force DensityHistogram to draw empty bins?

Tags: plotting, legending, charts

By default, when using the `"Count"` density specification, [`DensityHistogram`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DensityHistogram.html) does not plot empty bins. And thus the legend starts at 1.

So, is there a way to force `DensityHistogram` to draw bins containing no data **and** to ensure the *zero* value appears as part of the legend?

Comment: Have you tried the `GridLines` and the `PlotRange` options?

Comment: No, @Louis, I haven't. But I will ASAP ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Update:** To make colors corresponding to a given value the same across legends with the same color function use a second argument that specifies the range of values:

```
ClearAll[legendF2]
legendF2[values_, range_, zerocolor_: White, cf_: "M10DefaultDensityGradient"] := 
 SwatchLegend[Prepend[ColorData[cf] /@ Rescale[Rest@values, range], zerocolor], 
  values, LegendMarkerSize -> Large, LegendLayout -> {"ReversedColumn", 1}]
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[{legendF2[{0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 10}, {1, 10}], 
  legendF2[Range[0, 7], {1, 10}], 
  legendF2[{0, 3, 5, 6, 7}, {1, 10}, White, "Rainbow"], 
  legendF2[Range[0, 9], {1, 10}, Cyan, "Rainbow"]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Original answer:**

We can use a custom `SwatchLegend` that adds the 0 counts with a specified color to the colors for non-zero counts:

```
ClearAll[legendF]
legendF[values_, zerocolor_: White, cf_: "M10DefaultDensityGradient"] := 
 SwatchLegend[Prepend[ColorData[cf] /@ Rescale[Rest @ values], zerocolor], values, 
  LegendMarkerSize -> Large, LegendLayout -> {"ReversedColumn", 1}]
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[{legendF[{0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10}], legendF[Range[0, 7]], 
  legendF[{0, 2, 3, 5, 6, 10}, White, "Rainbow"], 
  legendF[Range[0, 7], Cyan, "Rainbow"]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

To use this with `DensityHistogram` we need to pass to `legendF` the bin counts used by `DensityHistogram`. We can get the bin counts using `HistogramList` with the same bin specs:

```
ClearAll[heightF]
heightF[binspecs_: Automatic][dt_] :=  HistogramList[dt, binspecs, "Count"][[2]]
```

***Examples:***

```
SeedRandom[1]
data = RandomVariate[BinormalDistribution[.5], 100];

Row[{DensityHistogram[data, Automatic, "Count", ImageSize -> 300, 
   ChartLegends -> legendF[Union @@ heightF[][data]]], 
  DensityHistogram[data, Automatic, "Count", ImageSize -> 300, 
   ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", ChartLegends -> legendF[Union @@ heightF[][data], White, 
    "Rainbow"]]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Using a different bin specification:

```
Row[{DensityHistogram[data, {{-3, -1, 0, 1, 3}}, "Count", 
   ImageSize -> 300, 
   ChartLegends -> legendF[Union @@ heightF[{{-3, -1, 0, 1, 3}}][data]]], 
  DensityHistogram[data, {{-3, -1, 0, 1, 3}}, "Count", 
   ImageSize -> 300, ColorFunction -> "Rainbow", 
   ChartLegends -> legendF[Union @@ heightF[{{-3, -1, 0, 1, 3}}][data], White, 
     "Rainbow"]]}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

**Showing empty bins:**

`DensityHistogram` does not render bins with zero counts. To show the bins with zero-counts with specified colors and tooltips, we can shift the counts by 1 so that all bins have positive count and use a custom color function and a custom chart element function:

```
ClearAll[colorF, cEF]
colorF[max_, zerocolor_: White, cf_: "M10DefaultDensityGradient"] := 
  If[# == 1, zerocolor, ColorData[cf] @ Rescale[#, {2, 1 + max}]] &;

cEF[zerocolor_: White] := {If[#2 == {}, zerocolor], 
   Tooltip[ChartElementData["Rectangle"][##], Length@#2]} &
```

***Examples:***

```
Row[DensityHistogram[data, Automatic, heightF[][data] + 1 &, 
    ImageSize -> 300, 
    ChartLegends -> legendF[Union @@ heightF[][data], White, #], 
    ChartElementFunction -> cEF[], 
    ColorFunction -> colorF[Max@heightF[][data], White, #], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False] & /@ 
  {"M10DefaultDensityGradient", "Rainbow"}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

```
Row[DensityHistogram[data, Automatic, heightF[][data] + 1 &, 
    ImageSize -> 300, 
    ChartLegends -> legendF[Union @@ heightF[][data], Cyan, #], 
    ChartElementFunction -> cEF[Cyan], 
    ColorFunction -> colorF[Max@heightF[][data], Cyan, #], 
    ColorFunctionScaling -> False] & /@ 
{"M10DefaultDensityGradient", "Rainbow"}, Spacer[10]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is really clever, @kglr! I can't test that right now, but that sounds promising.

Comment: @SylvainLeroux, have you had chance to test this?

Comment: I completely forgot :o

Comment: OK, @kglr, I checked that this morning. Your solution does work. I hope I will not forget the trick of using a custom _hspec_ parameter. Thank you very much for the _great_ answer!!!